# Mongo taking too long to sort in ascending order

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I am making queries on a mongo collection and want to sort them by date and get the K earliest documents by time. I have both date:1 and date:-1 indexes (although either one of them should work for sorting both in ascending or descending order).

Mongo is sorting pretty fast in descending order [1] but takes forever when I try to sort it in ascending order [2].

```
[1] db.collection.find(query).sort({date:-1}) //descending order 
[2]. db.collection.find(query).sort({date:1}) //ascending order
```

I tried using [1] and the retrieving the K earliest documents as follows

```
[3] for i in range(K):
        print db.collection.find(query).sort(date,-1)[collection.count() - i]["date"]
```

However, the cursor first iterates over collection.count() - K documents before it retrieves the required document and that takes too long because the collection size is close to 100,000.

I also tried using skip() as follows

```
[4] db.collection.find(query).sort(date,-1).skip(collection.count()-K)[0][date]
```

but that does not improve the time complexity either.

The main problem here is that mongo is not sorting the retrieved query in ascending order. I  will not have to bother with [3] or [4] if [2] works. Can anyone suggest why [2] is not working?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry  I forgot to add the {}. I am already passing in objects of the form {date: -1} and {date: 1}

Comment: Ok, thanks for fixing that. Well, I can tell you that you definitely only need to define the index once (order is irrelevant for a single-field index). Can you update your question to show the output of `db.collection.find(query).sort({date:1}).explain()`

Comment: I dropped both of the index on date and formed new ones. But I still face the same problem. Moreover, `db.collection.find(query).sort({date:1}).explain()`  is taking forever to run. The mongo shell basically hangs.

Comment: Does this mean there is a problem with the collection or the mongo instance on my machine?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Except that for me the sorting is slow in descending order and faster in ascending order

Comment: @user3791123 .. Did you find any solution??